# How to remove white space from HTML text

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, whitespace

How do I remove spaces in my code? If I parse this HTML with Nokogiri:

```
<div class="address-thoroughfare mobile-inline-comma ng-binding">Kühlungsborner Straße
                    10
                    </div>
```

I get the following output:

```
            Kühlungsborner Straße
            10
```

which is not left-justified.

My code is:

```
address_street = page_detail.xpath('//div[@class="address-thoroughfare mobile-inline-comma ng-binding"]').text
```

Comment: try `strip` i.e `address_street = page_detail.xpath('//div[@class="address-thoroughfare mobile-inline-comma ng-binding"]').text.strip`

Comment: Is this working ??

Comment: thanks this works fine

Comment: Your example HTML will not result in the output you're showing. Only `10` would be indented. Using `text` with `xpath`, similar to `search` returns concatenated text from the nodes returned by `xpath`'s NodeSet. Instead of using `text` with a method that returns a NodeSet, you should `map` each individual node's `text`, then `strip` those.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594657/128421 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="address-thoroughfare mobile-inline-comma ng-binding">Kühlungsborner Straße
                    10
                    </div>')
doc.search('div').text
# => "Kühlungsborner Straße\n                    10\n                    "
puts doc.search('div').text

# >> Kühlungsborner Straße
# >>                     10
# >>
```

The given HTML doesn't replicate the problem you're having. It's really important to present valid input that duplicates the problem. Moving on....

Don't use `xpath`, `css` or `search` with `text`. You usually won't get what you expect:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>foo</span>
      <span>bar</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('span').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('span') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdb6981bcd8 name="span" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdb6981b5d0 "foo">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fdb6981aab8 name="span" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fdb6981a054 "bar">]>]


doc.search('span').text
# => "foobar"
```

Note that `text` returned the concatenated text of all nodes found.

Instead, walk the NodeSet and grab the individual node's text:

```
doc.search('span').map(&:text)
# => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try `strip`:

```
address_street = page_detail.xpath('//div[@class="address-thoroughfare mobile-inline-comma ng-binding"]').text.strip
```